# Bar chart with colors

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jqplot

I'm trying to render two color of bars JQPLOT chart in a single series of data [i.e single dimension array] .

Please suggest is this possible to do with JQPLOT.

Comment: Can you describe what you want in a little more detail?  Sounds like you are after a stacked bar chart.  See example on this page: http://www.jqplot.com/tests/bar-charts.php

Comment: thanx for response. say for eg i have data like [200, 600, 700, 1000] in this 200,600 to be in separate color(black) and 700,1000 to be color(white) and for me the array length vary from 0 to 24 dynamically so i should change color of bar based on certain conditions.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the varyBarColor option.  Check their documentation on their website: http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/plugins/jqplot-barRenderer-js.html

```
seriesDefaults:{
  renderer:$.jqplot.BarRenderer,
  rendererOptions: {
    varyBarColor: true
  }
}
```